# Looking for text BBS software

Tags: server, software-center, ssh, telnet

I would like to know if there are text-based, bulleting board system forum servers for Ubuntu. Which can be used via telnet or ssh.

I was searching for this kind of software and came to this BBS client:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/pcmanx-gtk2/

which has this screenshot

[image: client connected to server]

I would like to know which software is that (the server) which look like a html forum but is text based.

Thank you

Comment: Close-voters: This question seems clear to me. Maybe someone can comment to explain how it's unclear or could be improved?

Comment: Synchronet. Here's instructions. Found on Google. http://www.pbnet.ro/?p=465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the OP; after more than one year trying to find a software like what I need I found the server of the screenshot:

https://www.ptt.cc/index.bbs.html

GitHub: https://github.com/ptt/pttbbs

Server: telnet://ptt3.cc

(I think it is taiwanese, try google translate)

But still is not what I need, I need something simple as a PHPBB like forum, only users, forums, maybe personal messages etc. I found no one to the day, still looking for one.

Answer (score 5):

Synchronet at http://synchro.net
Mystic BBS at http://mysticbbs.com

There are others, but those are probably the two best for now.

Comment: I should probably add that I've used both under both Linux and Windows and they are both good performers.  Synchronet is probably the most popular, however I have a soft spot for Mystic.

Answer (score 2):

Citadel has both a web and text-based interface and it seems like its capabilities are perfectly matched to your needs. To install Citadel in Ubuntu 14.04-18.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install citadel-server
```